# How to save input of html textarea after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently use the following code to save input after browser refresh.

```html
<style>textarea, input {
width:100%;
height:50px
}
</style>
<textarea class='' id='thetext' onkeyup='saveValue(this)'/><br/><br/>
<button id='' onclick='shift()'>Shift</button><br/><br/>
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("thetext");
function shift() { input.value = input.value.toUpperCase()}
</script>
<script>document.getElementById("thetext").value = getSavedValue("thetext");
  function saveValue(e){
            var id = e.id;  
            var val = e.value;  
            localStorage.setItem(id, val);
        }
       function getSavedValue  (v){
            if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
                return "";
            }
            return localStorage.getItem(v);
        }</script>
```

When a user enters something in the textarea, and leaves the window, the textarea gets stored in local storage, thanks to the onkeyup event listener.

However, if the user presses the shift button and leaves the browser, the uppercase text value doesn't get stored in textarea because there's no onkeyup action after button press.

I tried various event listeners instead of onkeyup, like onblur, onunload but none of them are working. Is there any event listener which can record the actions then and there? Or any way else?

PS - This code isn't working on Stackoverflow, don't know why, however it's working on my webpage. So, Please ignore this issue.

Comment: Please include all the code; it's hard to tell the context for when/where you are calling `replace()` and `concat()`.

Comment: I only see where you're overwriting the value into the DOM element, where does the localStorage item get updated with .setItem after the value is changed?

Comment: @ChrisW, I hope this edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the `saveValue()` method after you´ve done all your stuff you need with the input.

Answer (score 0):

just update the saved value by calling the `savevalue()` method you defined like this `input.value = input.value.replace(); input.saveValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your own environment.

```html
<form>
    <input name="first" placeholder="first" />
    <input name="last" placeholder="last" />
</form>

<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const FORM_DATA = 'FORM-DATA';

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(FORM_DATA);
        if (!fromStorage) return;

        const json = JSON.parse(fromStorage);

        for (const input of form.querySelectorAll('input')) {
            input.value = json[input.name];
        }
    });

    form.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        const formData = Object.fromEntries([...new FormData(form)]);
        localStorage.setItem(FORM_DATA, JSON.stringify(formData));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Save input after refreshing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" />

    <script>
        function saveValue(inputElement) {
                if (!inputElement) throw new Error('inputElement param is required');

                const { id, value } = inputElement;

                if (!id) throw new Error('inputElemend should have an id attribute');

                localStorage.setItem(id, value);
            }

        function getSavedValue(inputElement) {
            if (!inputElement) throw new Error('inputElement param is required');

            const { id } = inputElement;

            if (!id) throw new Error('inputElemend should have an id attribute');

            const value = localStorage.getItem(id);

            return value;
        }

        const input = document.querySelector('#myInput');

        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            saveValue(event.target)
        });

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            const value = getSavedValue(input);
            input.value = value;
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```